# AdblockPlus rule to allow everything within a specific IFrame

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, adblock

I'm playing a browsergame where you can earn ingame-premium-currency by watching various ads/movies/special offers/etc. My Firefox Addon Adblock Plus is doing a pretty good job in blocking all those ads - which prevents me from getting the emeralds since the scripts don't recognize the ad as being watched (which is okay).

These special ads are loaded in an IFrame from various external domains. So roughly, the structure is like this:
`MainSite@DomainA > iframe#gameIframeID@DomainA > iframe#adIframeID@DomainB`

So the MainSite contains an iframe with the game, which contains another iframe with the ads.

Since I am new to writing ABP-Rules, I didn't find a working solution so far.
**How can I create an ABP exception rule, that allows everything within the iframe with the id (or class) *adIframeID***, so that the ad and necessary scripts are loaded correctly, but the ads on the MainSite are still blocked as normal?

I know how to whitelist a specific domain, so I could whitelist the complete ad domain, but this domain might change and I only want their ads inside this game and nowhere else ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the iFrame has a URL associated with it (i.e. not an anonymous iFrame) you could write a filter as such:

`@@||example.com/iframe?showad=true$subdocument,document,domain=foo.com`

> Given that the URL of the iFrame is "https://example.com/iframe?showad=true" and that the domain the iFrame is shown on is "foo.com".

Such a filter will whitelist the iFrame (subdocument) and everything inside it (document).